# rollmean with grouped data.table returns a logical

Tags: r, data.table, mean

I am trying to use rollmean from the package zoo in a data.table while grouping data.

It works fine when all groups have enough data:

```
library(data.table)
dt = data.table(x=rep(c("a","b"),10),y=rnorm(20))

dt[,.(ma=rollmean(y, k = 7, fill=NA,align="right")), by = .(x)]
```

But when one of the groups has too little data, it returns an error

```
dt2 = data.table(x=rep(c("c"),1),y=rnorm(1))

dt3=rbind(dt,dt2)
dt3[,.(ma=rollmean(y, k = 7, fill=NA,align="right")), by = .(x)]
```

Here's the error message:

> Column 1 of result for group 3 is type 'logical' but expecting type 'double'. Column types must be consistent for each group.

It seems to happen because rollmean returns a logical (a mix of `TRUE` and `NA`) when it doesn't have enough data
Given that my data is always positive I use the following trick to make my code run anyway

```
dt4=dt3[,.(ma=rollmean(y, k = 7, fill=-1,align="right")), by = .(x)]
dt4[ma==-1,ma:=NA]
dt4
```

Is there a proper/better way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use the `NA_real_` instead of `NA` as by default it would be `NA_logical_`

```
dt3[x == 'c', class(rollmean(y, k = 7, fill = NA, align = 'right'))] 
#[1] "logical"
```

With `NA_real_` in `fill`, it would work fine

```
dt3[,.(ma=rollmean(y, k = 7, fill=NA_real_,align="right")), by = .(x)]
#    x          ma
# 1: a          NA
# 2: a          NA
# 3: a          NA
# 4: a          NA
# 5: a          NA
# 6: a          NA
# 7: a  0.19653855
# 8: a -0.05506344
# 9: a -0.17022022
#10: a -0.28731762
#11: b          NA
#12: b          NA
#13: b          NA
#14: b          NA
#15: b          NA
#16: b          NA
#17: b  0.02117906
#18: b -0.07079598
#19: b -0.05393943
#20: b  0.04511924
#21: c          NA
    x          ma
```

In other groups, it is also creating `NA`, but the difference is that it gets coerced to numeric NA when there are non-NA elements